# Invalid Sass variable when using number (with and without px)

Tags: css, variables, sass

I am using Sass for a project and I ran into an issue with variables. I'm specifically using the "*.sass" format and not "*.scss"

The error says: Invalid variable: "$weightBold = 700"

I can use variables for colors like this "$darkGrey: #333333" without errors, but I do get an error when I try to use a number for font-weight "$weightBold = 700" or width "$mediumWidth = 300px"

Answer (score 4):

There is nothing wrong with the number, use : instead of =

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `:` instead of `=` to assign a value to the variables:

```
$weightBold: 700;
$darkGrey: #333333;
$mediumWidth: 300px;
```

You can see some examples on the [official documentation](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#variables_):

> The most straightforward way to use SassScript is to use variables. Variables begin with dollar signs, and are set like CSS properties.
>
> ```
> $width: 5em;
> ```